# How to add a line break when using document.getElementByID

Tags: javascript

I am passing a javascript variable which contains a string in one sentence. So while displaying the variable, I want to break the sentence in 2 lines like this i.e.

Madhapur, Hyderabad

India-500081

```js
let streetName ='Madhapur, Hyderabad India-500081';

function render() {
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = streetName ;
}
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
<button onclick="render()">display</button>
```

Note this doesn't work : `let streetName ='Madhapur, Hyderabad \n India-500081'`

Comment: Put a `<br>` in the string. You're creating **HTML**. Just like in your normal HTML markup, a simple newline is treated like a space character. You have to use explicit markup to format the text.

Comment: side note: `getElementById` not `getElementByID` (javascript is case senitive)

Comment: It still displays it as a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to use CSS [white-space: pre-line](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)

```js
let streetName ='Madhapur, Hyderabad \n India-500081';

function render() {
  document.getElementById('result').textContent = streetName ;
}
```

```css
#result {
  white-space: pre-line
}
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
<button onclick="render()">display</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use br tag.

```js
let streetName ='Madhapur, Hyderabad<br/> India-500081';

function render() {
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = streetName ;
}
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
<button onclick="render()">display</button>
```

Comment: It still display the <br> as string literal

Comment: I can't see. Please check again.

Comment: @KirillSavik, I think OP means when you inspect the #result div, you will see a `<br>` in between and he just wants the string without any extra element.

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to add \n inside html and carryage return in html is done with `<br>`

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using innerHTML, you can use

````js
```
let streetName = "Madhapur, Hydrabad <br> India - 500081";

function render() {
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = streetName ;
}
```
````

```html
<div id="result"></div>
<button onclick="render()">display</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.innerHTML` (not `.innertext`) with the tag

```
document.getElementById(`pId`).innerHTML = `1st line text  <br> second line text`
or with the old concat way :
document.getElementById(`pId`).innerHTML = "1st line text" + "<br>" + "second line text"
```

tip : keep in mind that every time u use getElementById on same tag it delete the inner text and replace with new , so try to save all changes into a var and then .innerHTML=urVar